# How to specify access rights to projects in svn repository through apache in debian

Tags: svn, apache2, debian

can anybody tell me whether the following approach is correct or not?

[groups]

team1=user1
team2= user2.user3

[/]
@team1=rw

[subversion:/myproject1]
@team=rw

Answer (score 0):

this is the config I use (in svn_access_file, your file name could be diff)

```
[groups]
my_group_name = my_user_id, his_user_id
my_group_name2 = my_user_id2, his_user_id2

[myreponame:/]
@my_group_name = rw

[myreponame:/mybranch/]
@my_group_name2 = rw
```

my repository root is in /usr/svnrepo/
my repository is /usr/svnrepo/myreponame

My Apache configuration is:

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /usr/svnrepo/
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn/svn_access_file
Satisfy Any
Require valid-user
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/svn/svn_auth_file
SVNAutoversioning on
</Location>
```

So, you approach is correct

Answer (score 0):

nope, try to limit access and see your repos are still rw accessed